# Iterate through mysql result with a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

Normally when you iterate through a mysql result you do something like this:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["some argument"];
    }
```

How do you do this with a for loop? This would be helpful so I can iterate through a certain portion of my results. I'm looking for something like:

```
 for($i = 5; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo $row[$i]["some argument"];
 }
```

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1**

Just to clarify, I need to loop through a *portion* of the results, which may mean rows 5 to 10 for example.

Also my result is a portion of rows from a table, not a table in it's entirety, so I would think that changing the my_sql query should not be a part of the answer.

Comment: I changed the c-syntax for loop to PHP syntax...

Comment: I do not agree with your edit. IMHO, using `LIMIT` is still the most correct way to get a subset (ie 5 to 10) of rows.

Comment: please indicate why changing the sql query is not part of the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you could use the [mysql_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) like this:

```
// Do your query here
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table");

for($i = 5; $i < 10; $i++){
   echo mysql_result($result, $i, "some argument");
}
```

**Edit** Noticed that my PHP-syntax was a bit off, corrected now.

Answer (score 4):

You can load the whole result set into an array, and access it as you ask:

```
$all_results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Append all rows to an array
    $all_results[] = $row;
}
```

Now you can access it as:

```
echo $all_results[3]['somecolumn'];
```

Or in a for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
  echo $all_results[$i]["somecolumn"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are wishing to wade through any particlar fields of subranges of rows then you can  consider

```
 mysql_result($result,$row_num,$field)
```

routine

it returns the field attributes value of row_num'th row in result

say if you want to get "some argument" field's value for an subrange of results rows you can considier following snippet

```
$result = mysql_query("some query");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=5;$i<$num_rows;$i++) {   // here I have used range 5 to max of result rows
    echo mysql_result($result,$i,"some argument"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, but if you just want to iterate over all returned rows using while is the simplest solution. Here's another:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

 for(int i = 0; i < $count; i++){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row["some argument"];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a forward running cursor, you would

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result
    if (!$row) break;
    echo $row["some argument"];
}
```

If you need a seekable cursor you need to pull the result into an array;

```
$rows=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[]=$row;
}

//.. later, maybe repeatedly

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    echo $rows[i]["some argument"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
    echo $row["some argument"];
 }
```